# [Java][Spring][AWS S3] What is memory efficient way to return large file (s3) from Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, amazon-s3

I would like to provide the download method from Spring Controller by download file from AWS S3.
This S3 file could not allow to download directly in public. That's why I create controller to provide download file due to security reason.
However, I have a concern on [current implementation](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/spring-boot-and-aws-s3-download-file/) that I copied from internet because it download S3 file to be byte array which consume a lot of memory. I afraid OOM issue from this code.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value= "/s3")
public class AWSS3Ctrl {

    @Autowired
    private AWSS3Service service;

    @GetMapping(value= "/download")
    public ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> downloadFile(@RequestParam(value= "fileName") final String keyName) {
        final byte[] data = service.downloadFile(keyName);
        final ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(data);
        return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .contentLength(data.length)
            .header("Content-type", "application/octet-stream")
            .header("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + keyName + "\"")
            .body(resource);
    }
}
```

From my understanding, I have to avoid to read byte array into memory by using Java InputStream.
However, I could not find the answer yet.
Could someone give me any suggestions?

Comment: The best way would be to return a "presigned url" that the caller can then use to download the file directly from S3.

Comment: `byte[] data = new byte[1024];` should fit in memory just fine.

Comment: @luk2302 yes, correct. I understand now.